# Como puedo ordenar los datos de un archivo .log en un array con c#

Tags: c#, array

Este es el codigo, funciono con un archivo txt, pero el log tiene caracteres diferentes, hay alguna forma de separarlo en unicamente 2 columnas? habia intentado separarlo en 3 o mas pero no pude mostrarlo en consola, puse los ":" pensando en separarlo así, pero hay mas datos que los usan como las Fechas, o el Path.

```
string filePath = @"C:\\Users\\MServin\\Documents\\test2.log";
            List<Datos> dato = new List<Datos>();
            List<String> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
            foreach (string lin in lines )
            {
                string[] entries = lin.Split(':', '-');
                Datos newData = new Datos();

                newData.Name = entries[0];
                
                newData.Text = entries[1];
                
                newData.Tres = entries[2];
                Console.WriteLine(newData.Tres;

                dato.Add(newData);
            }
            foreach (var i in dato)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" {i.Name} {i.Text} {i.Tres} ");
            }
```

Y este es el archivo que debo ler y separar en 2 columnas:

```
                    TLWin Session Data Log - TaskLink Version 9.20

Date Logged:        01-28-2022 10:53:54 AM
Task Name:      0000001_111_00
User ID:        Operator Mode
System:         PSV7000
Machine ID:     PSV7000:1582800001
Adapter:        Adapter: PA-G2708HIC (Id = 3250)

Device:         MICRON MT00QL892AB00E00-0A T-PBGA24
Data Source:        c:\flash_data\gea\un\5456465\5456465\000_254.bin
Sumcheck:       84585477
Process:        Continuity/Blank Check/ID Check/Erase/Program/Verify/Auto Secure/Mark/Vision
Process Status:     Job Begin Status: New Job, Job End Status: Completed
TLWin Session ID:   < none >

Job Start Time:     01-28-2022 10:44:58 AM
Job End Time:       01-28-2022 10:53:54 AM
Devices Total:      30
Devices Passed:     30
Devices Failed:     0
Overall Device Yield:   100.00%f
```

Comment: Si haces `string[] entries = lin.Split(':', '-');` con los dos puntos ":" para el split y luego `newData.Name = entries[0];`, en **entries** (tal como está tu código y el log que muestras) tendríamos por ejemplo (para la línea):
"*Date: Date: 10-10-22 11:22:03 Uno: sjdhkjdshk Dos: sadadads Tres: asdasdsdf*"

    entries[0] --> Date
    entries[1] -->  Date
    entries[2] -->  10-10-22 11
    entries[3] --> 22
    entries[4] --> 03 Uno
    entries[5] -->  sjdhkjdshk Dos
    entries[6] -->  sadadads Tres
    entries[7] -->  asdasdsdf

¿A que te refieres con **ordenar** este array?

Comment: Pon como te salen los datos en el fichero log

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede, pero no con un split, si no abriendo las lineas a mano...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer lo siguiente, primero crear tu clase de Datos

```
class Datos
{
    public string LLave { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Valor { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Después vamos a necesitar un método para poder procesar cada linea del log

```
Datos? LeerLineaLog(string? linea) {

    //Validar que la linea no este vacia y que tenga un valor al inicio
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linea) || linea.StartsWith(" "))
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Buscar el index del primer caracter :
    int index = linea.IndexOf(":");

    //Si no se encuentra regresar null
    if (index == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }
    
    //Obtener el valor de la llave
    string llave = linea.Substring(0, index);

    //Obtener el valor y con TrimStart quitar los espacios en blanco
    string valor = linea.Substring(index + 1).TrimStart();

    return new Datos() { LLave = llave, Valor = valor };
}
```

Y por ultimo leer el log

```
List<Datos> datos = new List<Datos>();

//Leer cada linea del archivo
foreach (var linea in File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\georg\Desktop\prueba\log.txt"))
{
    Datos? resultado = LeerLineaLog(linea);

    //Si el resultado es diferente de null agregarlo a la lista
    if (resultado != null)
    {
        datos.Add(resultado);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo necesitas con split también se puede hacer

```
Datos? LeerLineaLogSplit(string? linea)
{

    //Validar que la linea no este vacia y que tenga un valor al inicio
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linea) || linea.StartsWith(" "))
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Hacer el split
    string[] lineaSplit = linea.Split(":");

    //Si no se encuentra regresar null
    if (lineaSplit.Length == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Obtener el valor de la llave
    string llave = lineaSplit[0];

    string valor = "";
    //Recorrer la lista empezando en la posicion 1 para saltar el primer registro
    for (int i = 1; i < lineaSplit.Length; i++)
    {
        valor += lineaSplit[i];
    }

    return new Datos() { LLave = llave, Valor = valor.TrimStart() };
}
```

Comment: Hola, Buenos días, dusculpa la pregunta, pero como lo acomodaste? es que intente hacerlo, pero me da error en la parte del foreach en `var linea`

Comment: No se si tu aplicacion es de consola esa parte la puedes poner en el metodo main

Comment: Lo había puesto mal yo, pero ya quedo solucionado, muchas gracias por la ayuda.